# HTML5 required attribute for a group of multiple input types

Tags: angularjs, html

I have one div which contains multiple types of input types. i.e., text, radio, checkbox...
I want to make the div mandatory. That means If I check the radio or check box or enter a value into the text field the mandatory condition satisfies. i.e, selecting any one of them satisfies the condition. If all are left without any value I must display angular messages(ng-messages) below the div.
This code is generated dynamically from Javascript. So validations should be done when I submit the form.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"><!--This div is mandatory-->


<input type="checkbox" name="div1" value="SomeValue" ng-model="vm.check1">Some<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="div1" value="SomeValue2" ng-model="vm.check2">Some2<br/>

<input type="radio" name="div1" value="Male">Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="div1" value="Female">Female<br/>
<input type="text" name="div1" ng-model="text1"><br/>
</div>

<div></div><!--Should display ng-messages here if none of the above selected.-->
<br/><br/>
<div id="div2"><!--This div is mandatory-->
<input type="checkbox" name="div2" value="SomeValue" ng-model="vm.check3">Some<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="div2" value="SomeValue2" ng-model="vm.check4">Some2<br/>
</div>
<div></div><!--Should display ng-messages here if none of the above selected.-->
```

is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do that just by wrapping all group of input fields under `fieldset` and then apply `required` attribute over that `fieldset`.

Make sure name attribute of each field should be different in order to consider each field as different. It can be same name for gender radio button.

```
<!--Below field input fields are mandatory now-->
<fieldset id="div1" required="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="SomeValue" ng-model="vm.check1">Some<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="SomeValue2" ng-model="vm.check2">Some2<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br/>
  <input type="text" name="text1" ng-model="text1"><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Learn new thing :)